# PHP Variables inside JQuery/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have some javascript/jquery code and need to some php into it be the syntax seems to be wrong...

This is what I'm doing:

```
$.post("myphp.php?something=$phpvariablehere",{ etc....
```

The result right now is that it's taking ***$phpvariablehere*** as a string and not the value of it.

Anyone know the right syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

`$.post("myphp.php?something=<?php echo $phpvariablehere; ?>",{ etc....`

It would be worth while understanding the difference between server-side (PHP) and client-side (Javascript) languages, and how/why they interact with each other. you can't swap between two different languages like you originally attempted - you need to declare a PHP section using these:

`<?php ... ?>`

or you can insert the variable directly by using:

`<?= $phpvariablehere ?>`

Answer (score 4):

Not really a JS question, but here you go:

`$.post("myphp.php?something=<?php echo $phpvariablehere ?>"`

Answer (score 2):

Or, for a more readable version (with short tags allowed on the server):

```
$.post("myphp.php?something=<?= $phpvariablehere ?>"...
```

Also, your page must be .php, not .js, for this to work with the default settings.